# Part specification is longer than depth of object

Tags: plotting

everyone! I'm a bit new to Mathematica. Could you help me plot this:

```
TheoreticalT[n2_, k2_, 
   w_] := (2*cn2[n2, k2]*(n1 + n3)*E^(
     I (2 \[Pi] w  d2 (cn2[n2, k2] - 1))/
      c))/((n1 + cn2[n2, k2])*(n3 + cn2[n2, k2]) - (cn2[n2, k2] - 
        n1)*(cn2[n2, k2] - n3)*E^(I (2 cn2[n2, k2] 2 \[Pi] w d2 )/c));
TheoreticalT2[n4_, k4_, 
   w_] := (2*cn4[n4, k4]*(n1 + n3)*E^(
     I (2 \[Pi] w  d2 (cn4[n4, k4] - 1))/
      c))/((n1 + cn4[n4, k4])*(n3 + cn4[n4, k4]) - (cn4[n4, k4] - 
        n1)*(cn4[n4, k4] - n3)*E^(I ( 2 cn4[n4, k4] 2 \[Pi] w d2)/c));
TheoreticalT3[n6_, k6_, 
   w_] := (2*cn6[n6, k6]*(n1 + n3)*
     E^(-I (2 \[Pi] w  d2 (cn6[n6, k6] - 1))/
      c))/((n1 + cn6[n6, k6])*(n3 + cn6[n6, k6]) - (cn6[n6, k6] - 
        n1)*(cn6[n6, k6] - n3)*E^(I ( 2 cn6[n6, k6] 2 \[Pi] w d2)/c));
```

I followed the same method in saving and plotting equations from my other equations but it doesn't work for this one. Here's what I've been doing:

```
(*saving the Theoretical Transmittance data*)
TheoreticalTdata = 
  Table[{freq[[i]], Re[TheoreticalT[[i]]], Im[TheoreticalT[[i]]]}, {i,
     1, np}];
TheoreticalT2data = 
  Table[{freq[[i]], Re[TheoreticalT2[[i]]], 
    Im[TheoreticalT2[[i]]]}, {i, 1, np}];
TheoreticalT3data = 
  Table[{freq[[i]], Re[TheoreticalT3[[i]]], 
    Im[TheoreticalT3[[i]]]}, {i, 1, np}];

(*Plotting the Theoretical Transmittance*)
ListPlot[{Table[{freq[[i]], Abs[TheoreticalT[[i]]]}, {i, 1, np}], 
  Table[{freq[[i]], Abs[TheoreticalT2[[i]]]}, {i, 1, np}], 
  Table[{freq[[i]], Abs[TheoreticalT3[[i]]]}, {i, 1, np}]},
 PlotRange -> {{fmin, fmax}, All}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency (THz)", "Transmittance"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Transmittance", PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
(*Legend:
Red: Sample 1, Green: Sample 2, Blue: Sample 3*)
```

And here are some of the errors that I've been encountering:

> Part::partd: Part specification TheoreticalT[[1]] is longer than depth
> of object.

Hope you could help. Thanks!

Comment: Please generate a MRE ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that one can understand your problem.

Comment: Okidoki. Thank you!

Comment: The upper code section defines TheoreticalT, TheoreticalT1 and TheoreticalT2 each as a function taking three arguments. In the lower code section an expression like TheoreticalT[[1]] is not a function call but attempts to take the first element of TheoreticalT (which does not exist, hence the error message). Or did you have in mind an expression which refers to either of the TheoreticalT functions?

Comment: @user7515079 Yes, you are right. The upper part of the code is the definitions of the functions TheoreticalT, TheoreticalT1, TheoreticalT2. How will I be able to call the function so that I can save (and export) it and plot it?

Comment: I assume that the first two arguments (n, k) to your functions TheoreticalT are parameters whereas w is the continuous argument which serves as the abscissa. In this case you can plot the functions as Plot[{TheoreticalT[1, 1, t], TheoreticalT1[1, 1, t], TheoreticalT2[1, 1, t]}, {t, 0, 2}]. Here, I chose all parameters n and k to be equal to 1 and set the plot-range to the interval [0, 2]. If this is what you are looking for, you could as a next step turn this into a function that can be called for different parameter values.