# Part specification is longer than the depth of object

Tags: replacement, warning-messages

I want to solve the function `lns50` all the values are Part 1 of an List

```
ri = ri[[1]]
rj = rj[[1]]
kij = kij[[1]]
yi = yi[[1]]
phm = phm[[1]]
ylm = ylm[[1]]
plm = plm[[1]]
yhm = yhm[[1]]
si = si[[1]]
ss = ss[[1]]
sf = sf[[1]]
mi = mi[[1]]
tsi = tsi[[1]]
δi = δi[[1]]
dri = dri[[1]]
drj = drj[[1]]
lij = lij[[1]]Δ
lns50 = Sqrt[(
   (Out[12] Δri[[1]])^2 + (Out[13] Δrj[[
        1]])^2
    + (Out[14] Δkij[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        15] Δyi[[1]])^2
    + (Out[16] Δphm[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        17] Δylm[[1]])^2
    + (Out[18] Δplm[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        19] Δyhm[[1]])^2
    + (Out[20] Δsi[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        21] Δmi[[1]])^2
    + (Out[22] Δtsi[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        23] Δδi[[1]])^2
    + (Out[24] Δlij[[1]])^2)]
```

So i only need to change the "Position" of List by changing [[1]] to [[2]]

```
ri = ri[[2]]
rj = rj[[2]]
kij = kij[[2]]
yi = yi[[2]]
phm = phm[[2]]
ylm = ylm[[2]]
plm = plm[[2]]
yhm = yhm[[2]]
si = si[[1]]
ss = ss[[1]]
sf = sf[[1]]
mi = mi[[1]]
tsi = tsi[[2]]
δi = δi[[1]]
dri = dri[[1]]
drj = drj[[1]]
lij = lij[[1]]
Δ
lns50 = Sqrt[(
   (Out[12] Δri[[1]])^2 + (Out[13] Δrj[[
        1]])^2
    + (Out[14] Δkij[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        15] Δyi[[1]])^2
    + (Out[16] Δphm[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        17] Δylm[[1]])^2
    + (Out[18] Δplm[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        19] Δyhm[[1]])^2
    + (Out[20] Δsi[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        21] Δmi[[1]])^2
    + (Out[22] Δtsi[[1]])^2 + (Out[
        23] Δδi[[1]])^2
    + (Out[24] Δlij[[1]])^2)]
```

My problem is, that Mathematica gives the error message `Part::partd: Part specification is longer than depth of object´

Please tell me if you have any clue what I need to tell Mathematica instead.

I tried `ClearAll` but it didn't work.

Comment: The way you determined variables above (that is, `ri = ri[[1]]` and so on) 1) Mathematica does not know that `ri` has several parts. You did not define them. Mathematica at this point understands it as an object having only a Head (that is, `ri[[0]]`. This causes the message "Part specification ri[[1]] is longer than depth of object". 2) As soon as you equate `ri = ri[[1]]` you cause an infinite recursion process. Mathematica breaks it at a certain step. This causes the message "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of ri[[1]]".

Comment: Continuation: 3) In general, I would not recommend using "Out" to refer to a previously calculated object. It is not forbidden, but in case you will recalculate the result, it may cause heavy errors. It is much better to give a name to each result, and to address these results by those names.

Comment: @alexei

 Mathematica should know that `ri` has several parts 
I didn´t post them but i defined them like:

`ri = {53, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
  19, 20, 21}`

Comment: Same title (almost): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226608/part-specification-is-longer-than-depth-of-object

Comment: @rolo1967 It has probably forgotten it. Try to evaluate this definition once more. And to avoid the infinite recurrence process, instead of the direct redefinition:  `ri = ri[[1]]` try to do it indirectly: `riA = ri[[1]]; ri=riA;`